# Limits to the principle of explosion

Tags: logic

In propositional logic, the principle of explosion can be proven in the following way.

1. $\phi \wedge \neg\phi$ (hypothesis)
2. $\phi$ (simplification, 1)
3. $\phi \vee \psi$ (disjunction introduction, 2)
4. $\neg\phi$ (simplification,1)
5. $\psi$ (disjunctive syllogism, 3, 4)

Hence, $\phi \wedge \neg\phi \to \psi$

I am interested in the special case where $\psi = \phi \wedge \neg\phi$. Then we obtain;

1. $\phi \wedge \neg\phi$ (hypothesis)
2. $\phi$ (simplification, 1)
3. $\phi \vee (\phi \wedge \neg\phi)$ (disjunction introduction, 2)
4. $\neg\phi$ (simplification,1)
5. $\phi \wedge \neg\phi$ (disjunctive syllogism, 3, 4)

Hence $\phi \wedge \neg\phi \to \phi \wedge \neg\phi$, a tautology.

What does it mean that (1) is the same as (5)? Is $\phi \wedge \neg\phi$ an exception to the rule that *from an inconsistency everything follows*?

Comment: You proved $\phi \land \lnot \phi$, so it does seem to follow from itself.  Could you clarify why you think it is unusual that, when you know that $\psi$ could be any sentence, in particular $\psi$ could be the sentence you started with?

Comment: It seemed weird to me what If I start with a statement, make a bunch of transformation on it, then end up with the same statement I started with that I could then claim that I have done real work (e.g. proving it).

Comment: You didn't prove $\phi \land \lnot \phi$ without assumptions, though; you proved that if you assume $\phi \land \lnot \phi$ then you can conclude $\phi \land \lnot \phi$.  So all you have actually proved is that the statement implies itself.